# When proving a sequence converges to a value p, is there more than one \epsilon value to use?

Tags: real-analysis

For example I want to prove that the sequence: 
$\left \{\frac{3n+5}{2n+7} \right \}$ converges to $\frac{3}{2}$

It appears to work with $N > \frac{1}{4\epsilon}$. However, my book gives me the answer that $N > \frac{3}{\epsilon}$

Are both answers correct? 
THanks!

Comment: If it works with $N>\frac{1}{4 \epsilon}$ then it will definitely work with $N>\frac{3}{\epsilon}$. But the reverse might not hold. It's not uncommon to use much blunter estimates than the optimal one when proving things like this.

Comment: @herro See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In this case it looks like $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is close to being tight, so I don't know how you would've proved it with $\frac{1}{4 \epsilon}$.

Comment: @Ian I obtained $n>\frac{11/4}{\epsilon}-7/2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You're right, I made a minor arithmetic error, getting 4 where I should have had 11.

Comment: @Ian No worry.  I can't count as high as the number of minor/careless errors I've made - in math and otherwise.  ;-)